# Track owner and price in Ethereum Pet Shop

Tags: solidity, transactions, truffle, addresses

I've been following along with the [Ethereum Pet Shop](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop) tutorial, and I'm fascinated by how all of this works.

I have a few questions, though.

Before I get into it, here's the code:

pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

```
contract Adoption {
    Pet[16] pets;

    struct Pet {
        address owner;
        uint256 price;
    }

    function returnEth() public payable {
    msg.sender.transfer(msg.value);
    }
    // Adopting a pet
    function adopt(uint petId) public payable returns (uint) {
        require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);
        require(msg.value >= pets[petId]['price'] * 0.5);
        pets[petId] = Pet({owner: msg.sender, price: 100});
        return petId;
        //return value;
    }
    // Retrieving the adopters
    function getAdopters() public view returns (Pet[16]) {
        return pets;
    }


}
```

I understand that there are 16 total pets, with numeric IDs ranging from 0-15, inclusive. I also understand that only one person is able to "own" a pet at one time.

Is the *current* owner of a pet immutable? If so, how do I change this property?

Let's say that after a user "buys" a pet, I want to change the price of the pet to .5 * initialPrice, where `initalPrice` does not currently exist. The remaining balance in eth in the contract is then returned to the first buyer. What would that logic look like?

I assume I'd declare some variable `initialPrice` somewhere in my contract, such that `initialPrice` is equal to some arbitrary value in wei, and then add something similar to the following line:

`require(msg.value == initialPrice * .5);`

How would I then return the remaining eth to the previous owner?

Please let me know if any of this is unclear.

Edit: I've been trying to use the code from the first, answer, but am unable to compile the contract. The error I'm getting is below:

`Adoption.sol:19:17: TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct Adoption.Pet storage ref.
        pets[petId] = msg.sender;
                      ^--------^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current owner is not immutable. In order to change it, simply call the `adopt()` function from a different address.

Regarding the price, your approach works if you want to have the same price for all the pets. In order to have different prices for different pets, you could define a `pet` `struct`, like this:

```
struct Pet {
  address owner;
  uint256 price;
}
```

and instead of storing the adopters like `address[16] public adopters;`, keep them like:

```
Pet[16] pets;
```

Then require the price to be greater or equal to `price * .5` and eventually increase the price:

```
require(msg.value >= pets[petId].price * 0.5);
pets[petId].price = pets[petId].price * 0.5;
```

In order to send funds to the previous owner, you can send them **before** setting the new owner:

```
pets[petId].owner.send(your_amount)
```

Comment: Using that code, I have the following error when compiling. `TypeError: Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is struct Adoption.Pet storage ref)
  require(msg.value >= pets[petId]['price'] * 0.5);` New to Solidity so I'm not sure how to approach debugging. Any ideas?

Comment: The price has to be `uint256` or something and not an address as it is now. I am not at computer right now and can't edit my answer.

Comment: `uint price;` within the struct still results in the same error.

Comment: any idea why that's happening?

Comment: Please ask another question, showing the full smart contract code that you have until now and a specific issue. If you think my suggestion regarding how to approach the problem is good, please accept this answer as the solution to this question.

Comment: my contract's code is in the question, and I'd accept your answer if it would compile.

Comment: your **old** contract code is in the question. The **new** contract code should have a new question.

Comment: Anyway, I've updated the code, see if it compiles now.

Comment: it does not. I've updated my original question with your changes (perhaps I'm doing something incorrectly) along with the error I get in the console. Sorry if I am not being clear.

Comment: Please have a closer look at the updates I made to my code, because there are some updates that are not reflected in your updated smart contract.

Also, the error that you're getting now is because you're assigning an address to something that expects a `Pet` structure. Since you changed the things that you store in the `adopters` array from addresses to `Pet`s, the previous code doesn't work.

That's the issue with asking multiple questions at once and trying to iterate the development in a single question: the updated version doesn't reflect the original question.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only change not reflected is the absence of `pets[petId].owner.send(your_amount)`. All I'm trying to do here is compile your suggested changes.

Comment: try with `pets[petId] = Pet({owner: msg.sender, price: 100})`

Comment: that seems to work, but the `require(msg.value >= pets[petId].price * 0.5);` statement still fails to compile with the same TypeError.

Comment: what exactly says *the same TypeError*?

Comment: I replaced `pets[petId].price = pets[petId].price * 0.5;` with your change, which was `pets[petId] = Pet({owner: msg.sender, price: 100})`. The line `require(msg.value >= pets[petId].price * 0.5);` still won't compile and I am seeing the same error from earlier. Nothing says "the same TypeError". Here's what I'm seeing (the same TypeError): `TypeError: Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is struct Adoption.Pet storage ref)
  require(msg.value >= pets[petId]['price'] * 0.5);`

Comment: try with `require(msg.value >= pets[petId].price * 0.5)`

Comment: `TypeError: Operator * not compatible with types uint256 and rational_const 1/2`